# Latitude and longitude to map tile set

Tags: javascript, maps, openstreetmap

On the link below [1] I can see how to get the URL of the tile for specific latlon.

```
var zoom = 15;
var lat = 47;
var lon = 8;
        
function long2tile(lon,zoom) { return (Math.floor((lon+180)/360*Math.pow(2,zoom))); }
function lat2tile(lat,zoom)  { return (Math.floor((1-Math.log(Math.tan(lat*Math.PI/180) + 1/Math.cos(lat*Math.PI/180))/Math.PI)/2 *Math.pow(2,zoom))); }
        
var x = long2tile(lon, zoom); // get x long2tile
var y = lat2tile(lat, zoom);  // get y lat2tile
        
tileUrl = "tile.osm.org/" + zoom + "/" + x + "/" + y + ".png"
```

What I want to know is how to get all the tile URL's for the surrounding tiles. Usually there is a grid of say 3x3 tiles and I'm looking in the one in the middle, that would be my base latlon. How do I get URL's for all the other neighboring tiles?

[1] http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#ECMAScript_.28JavaScript.2FActionScript.2C_etc..29

Comment: Modified your code to work for x & y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are just coordinates in a grid. Increase/decrease your x and y coordinates accordingly to get all surrounding tiles. Example:

[image]

Quoting from the Wiki:

> - X goes from 0 (left edge is 180 °W) to 2^zoom − 1 (right edge is 180 °E)
> - Y goes from 0 (top edge is 85.0511 °N) to 2^zoom − 1 (bottom edge is 85.0511 °S) in a Mercator projection
>
> For the curious, the number 85.0511 is the result of arctan(sinh(π)).
>   By using this bound, the entire map becomes a (very large) square.

Comment: Just a small sub question, the latlong for which I calculate the tile is in the middle of that tile or at top left corner?

Comment: If you want to get the surrounding tiles then your lat/lon pair is in the center.

Comment: I didn't mean which tile, but within a given tile, the latlong is in the center of that tile, or at the top left corner of that tile?

Comment: I guess that depends on the function you are using. According to the wiki most tile2latlon functions return the latitude and longitude of the NW-corner of the tile. This isn't stated for your function, though. So unfortunately I can't answer this question.

Comment: Ok, I see that the latlong can be anywhere inside the tile, which makes sense, as the tiles are not dynamically generated. So tile is fixed from certain latlong into a rectangle.